# How to troubleshoot a hanging Paho Python Mqtt Single Publish

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm looking for ways to trouble shoot issues publishing to a local mosquitto installation (on a RPi).

I find commands from mosquitto_sub and _pub work ok, as is mqtt-os-status.

I've installed paho-mqtt with pip and I'm trying the following:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
publish.single("paho/test/single", "boo-localhost", hostname="localhost")
```

The python command prompt doesn't return... it's been a few minutes since I last tried and I'm just leaving it to see if I get an error message.

Does anyone have any suggestions for where to start troubleshooting? or has anyone come across anything similar?

Matt

Comment: If you have just installed mosquitto from the 'Raspbian repository' then I suggest you install the latest version from the 'Mosquitto Debian repository' instead, http://mosquitto.org/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/ a good guide is here if you need help installing it  http://jpmens.net/2013/09/01/installing-mosquitto-on-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thanks Matt, installing from the mosquitto repo did the job. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just installed mosquitto from the 'Raspbian repository' then I suggest you install the latest version from the '[Mosquitto Debian repository](http://mosquitto.org/2013/01/mosquitto-debian-repository/)' instead.

A good guide is [here](http://jpmens.net/2013/09/01/installing-mosquitto-on-a-raspberry-pi/) if you need help installing it.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
publish.single("paho/test/single", "boo-localhost", hostname="localhost", protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31)
```

It's possible your broker doesn't support MQTTv3.1.1 and the way that it handles this unknown protocol is unfriendly to the Paho library.